# Full name parsing and comparing against database

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, string-comparison

I have text box to enter full name of a user on a website. I get the user firstname, lastname and middlename/initials from database from database using email.

Please help me in parsing fullname entered by user and compare against the db values.

```
positionFirst = name.IndexOf(" ")
positionLast = name.LastIndexOf(" ")
firstName = name.Substring(0, positionFirst)
lastName = name.Substring(positionLast + 1)
middleName = name.Substring(positionFirst, positionLast - positionFirst)
```

I have the above solution working if the full name has just two spaces. I am failing where first name or last name has spaces. Please provide me some regex or suggest me a better way to compare the string with spaces.

Example Names:

firstName | initials | lastName - JAMES BETH |S |   WALSER KING

firstName | initials | lastName - VENKATA RAMESH    | NULL | KURUBA RAYUDU VERI

firstName | initials | lastName - J W YIN | B | WRIGHT

firstName | initials | lastName - J W Rao | Null |  Null

Comment: Names... names are weird. You have no idea the can of worms you're about to open.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have text boxes for each field (first name, middle, last) instead of trying to parse a string with an unknown amount of spaces.

Comment: Even the user of the application does not the exact first, last and middle of other person

Comment: @user1169809 I don't really see how that effects the problem of separating the name into it's parts. From what I can tell you need to first separate the name into the 3 parts first, middle, last and then compare to the database. My answer solves the problem of separating the name into parts. You haven't provided any information about your database or how you are trying to compare the values, but if it's a matter of not knowing exact spelling you can try using the SQL like keyword. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: @user1169809 if the person entering the name doesn't know where the first name ends and the middle name begins, you can try combining the database name columns into one full name value and comparing the whole first name string against it in your query. Something like *UNTESTED* `SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, MiddleName, LastName) as FullName    WHERE fullNameString LIKE FullName`